# Is there a way pull AdAccount invoices via Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-business-sdk

I'm trying to automate the task of pulling invoices from multiple AdAccounts on Facebook.
* I'm using their Business Manager API without the 'month-end-invoicing'.

Iv'e Tried using getBusinessInvoices() call using the PHP-SDK as a system user of a business owning some apps and accounts with the following permissions:
 - financial analyst
 - Manage Ad Account for the Account asset
 - App Developer for the App asset
 - business_management, manage_pages and ads_management permissions

but the call returns an JSON Object that contains an empty array under named "data".

Given the fact that Facebook deprecated the transactions edge is there a way of pulling invoices straight from the AdAccount?

Does anyone has any experience with this issue?